# Does G-WAN support precompiled header?

Tags: g++, g-wan, precompiled-headers

Does G-WAN support precompiled header?

For example if I have really big `test.h` file in the `/csp` folder, and then I compile it using:

```
$ g++ test.h
$ ls test.h*
test.h     test.h.gch
```

Would G-WAN use the `test.h.gch` file when this file is included in a C++ servlet?

Answer (score 1):

> Would G-WAN use this `test.h.gch` precompiled file when this header is used by a C++ servlet?

First, doing it manually will work if `g++` is looking for precompiled headers in their source code directory (they might instead be treated as temporary files created by `g++` in a temporary directory).

Second, I am not sure that precompiled files are used by G-WAN because the answer depends on the persistence of `g++` temporary files and the ability for consecutive compilations to lookup these files - a thing that we have never traced (we do not use C++ for our developments).

You can check this easily by compiling twice the same servlet and measuring the time. If the second compilation (after the servlet was modified) is faster than the first one then pre-compiled headers are used.

Procompiled headers speeds-up the compilation of C++ project (C++ is much slower to compile than plain C because (a) it is immensely more complex and (b) overloading allows the language syntax to hide completely different semantics... which level of complexity is decided by the C++ programmer).